# How to change a SplitContainer border color?

Tags: c#, vb.net, system.drawing

I have the border style set to FixedSingle. How can I change the color of the fixed single line around the panels? Instead of black I need it to be a light grey.

Comment: Change the BackColor of the SlitContainer and then use panels to host your controls. Adjust the size/anchor of the panels to show the margin you'd like to see. A docked panel with have just leave the splitter color showing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Handle the `Paint` event for each the `SplitterPanel`s contained in the `SplitContainer` and draw your own border using the `ControlPaint.DrawBorder` method.

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    AddHandler SplitContainer1.Panel1.Paint, AddressOf Panel_Paint
    AddHandler SplitContainer1.Panel2.Paint, AddressOf Panel_Paint
End Sub

Private Sub Panel_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs)
    ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, e.ClipRectangle, Color.LightGray, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid)
End Sub
```